# Could we have the link button on mobile app too?

Tags: feature-request

Several times I tried to write an answer from my mobile phone and suddenly discovered that there is no "link" button there (there is only a single button to insert the picture). Few times this prevented me from providing sources for my answer that I had, and used for answering. When later back to the desktop computer, I was not able to find the same websites anymore. I think this is not a good thing. Even if this could be done with some complex markup, writing such a markup where even clipboard access is hindered looks very cumbersome.

As there is already a button to put the image into the answer, adding more buttons to that row would not take additional space on the screen of the mobile phone. I do not know if this would require some programming effort or just a setting in some advanced configuration.

Comment: I think this is a general problem and should probably be asked on main [meta.se].

Comment: Note that you can just paste the link directly into your post; it won't be pretty, but it can be cleaned up in edit.

Comment: Links are often too long and garbled to simply copy paste them. I do not know how much individual stack exchange projects can be specifically configured.

Comment: As the mobile app is no longer supported, this isn't likely to happen.